# Iwasawa and $KAK$ Decomposition for Diff$(S^1)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

It is well known
$\newcommand{\Diff}{\operatorname{Diff}}$
 that the group $\Diff(S^1)$ of smooth diffeomorphisms of the circle behaves in many ways like $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. For example, if $S^1\subseteq \Diff(S^1)$ is the group of rotations then $\Diff(S^1)/S^1$ is an infinite dimensional complex domain (apparently this is due to Kirillov and Yuriev). This is analogous to the symmetric space $SL(2,\mathbb R)/S^1$ which is the complex upper half plane.

Now $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ has some very useful decompositions: the Iwasawa decomposition (or the $KAN$ decomposition) and the $KAK$ decomposition.

Does $\Diff(S^1)$ also have $KAN$ and $KAK$ decompositions?

Comment: The question is unclear. To "have a $KAK$ or $KAN$ decomposition" in an abstract topological group means nothing without further specification. For $KAK$ one option is that $K$ is required to be compact and $A$ abelian, but the usual $KAK$ decomposition refers to a particular decomposition and not any decomposition with $K$ compact and $A$ abelian.

Comment: The group $Diff(S^1)$ is a smooth Lie group locally diffeomorphic to a Frechet vector space. I am looking for "reasonable" decompositions analogous to $KAK$ and $KAN$, but the question is intentionally stated vaguely from this viewpoint. Ideally, I would like $K$ to be the group of rotations. Also note that for loop groups there is a $KAN$ decomposition.

Comment: I took the liberty of tweaking some formatting - I hope this is OK

Answer (score 7):

At least for the $KAN$ decomposition, there is a candidate.

Namely take $K$ the rotation group, $A$ the group of hyperbolic elements of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ fixing $0$ and $\infty$, and $N$ the group of diffeos fixing $0$ and tangent to the identity there.

Then $G=KAN$ is the group $Diff_+(\mathbb{S}^1)$, and the decomposition of elements is unique, as is easily checked.

No idea yet for the $KAK$ decomposition.